# Copy data from a pointer?

Tags: delphi, pointers, copy, record

```
...
  PAnalyzeInfo = ^TAnalyzeInfo;
  TAnalyzeInfo = record
    pPitch: array of Single;
    pEnergy: array of Single;
    pPitchAccent: array of Single;
    pEnergyAccent: array of Single;
    pDicAccent: array of Single;
    pScore: array of Single;
    pBoundary: Integer;
    szRecWord: array of array of AnsiChar;
    nRecWordNum: Integer;
    nFrameNum: Integer;
  end;
...
```

I have `pDataSource: PAnalyzeInfo` which contains data and I want to copy it to a new independent variable. `MyData : TAnalyzeInfo`.

Is it possible to copy the whole structure or adding it one bye one?

Answer (score 5):

In Delphi you can copy a record just by assigning it, thanks to compiler magic.

```
MyData := DataSource^;
```

The dynamic arrays are reference counted, so the assignment also takes care of the dynamic arrays as long as you don't need a real deep copy. With a simple assignment they just share the same memory.

If you don't want that you can copy them individually:

```
MyData.pPitch = Copy(pDataSource^.pPitch, Low(pDataSource^.pPitch), 
                                          High(pDataSource^.pPitch);
```

Comment: Dynamic arrays do not use copy on write. They are reference-counted like strings, but assigning an element of an array does not create a new copy of it as it would when assigning a character of a string.

Answer (score 4):

No, the dynamic arrays cannot be copied with a single copy command. You will have to:

1. Copy each non-array field
2. For each array

   1. Create a new array of the correct size in the target
   2. Copy the array members across

It would be much easier if the arrays were static. In that case copying the whole memory block would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can use move procedure declared in the system unit :
system.move(pDataSource^, MyData, sizeof(TAnalyzeInfo));

Comment: Well, but one has to be careful with the arrays. In a record, an array is only a pointer /to the actual array data/, so the new record and the original record will have members that point to the same arrays. The array data will not be copied -- there will only be one array of each member.

Comment: Not all arrays, only dynamic arrays (without bounds) are ptrs.

Comment: Don't do this. Every array in the structure in the question is a dynamic array, which are references and have reference counts. Using Move to copy it will copy the reference without altering the reference count; when there is only one reference left to the arrays (from disposing other copies), this remaining copy will have dangling pointers to deallocated data.

Comment: Yes, all are right. please consider the open / dynamic array an the reference count restriction. This dirty trick is only safe as long as the source is persistent and you only need to have a temporary copy (e.g. just for convenience) and only refer the value without any modification in the array elements.